# handle larg number of async jobs

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

problem: we have some IP Address, then we should to ping each one of them by period of time that specified by user, for example ping 192.168.0.1 every 400ms, ping 192.168.137.20 every 40000ms and etc... how we can handle situations like that in asynchronous way?

this is where i load targets information from database and create a sensor for each of them:

```
public class PingService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancel;        
    private List<PingSensor> _pings;
    private IRepository<IPDevice> _deviceRepository;


    public PingService()
    {
        _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _pings = new List<PingSensor>();
        _deviceRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<IPDevice>>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Action act = new Action(() =>
        {
            IQueryable<IPDevice> allDevices = _deviceRepository.GetAll();

            foreach (IPDevice device in allDevices)
            {
                PingResultCollector collector = new PingResultCollector(device);
                _pings.Add(new PingSensor(device.Address, collector, device.CheckDuration, _cancel.Token));
            }

            foreach (PingSensor _ping in _pings)
            {
                _ping.DoDiscovery();
            }
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(act);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancel.Cancel();
    }
}
```

and this is where we do ping and wait for delay specified by user, collect the response and...

```
    public class PingSensor
{
    private string _address;        
    Ping _ping;
    private bool lastRequestReplayed;
    private int _delay;        
    private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    private PingResultCollector _resultCollector;


    public PingSensor(string address, PingResultCollector resultCollector, int delay, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
    {
        _address = address;
        _cancellationToken = CancellationToken;
        _ping = new Ping();
        _resultCollector = resultCollector;

        _ping.PingCompleted += _ping_PingCompleted;
        _delay = delay;
    }

    void _ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        lastRequestReplayed = true;
        //_eventHandler(sender, e);

        if (_resultCollector != null)
            _resultCollector.CollectData(new PingStatus()
            {
                PingStatusId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Address = e.Reply == null ? "" : e.Reply.Address.ToString(),
                Status = e.Reply == null ? e.Error.Message : e.Reply.Status.ToString(),
                Target = e.UserState.ToString(),
                ResponseTime = e.Reply == null ? 0 : e.Reply.RoundtripTime,
                UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
            });
    }

    public void DoDiscovery()
    {
        lastRequestReplayed = true;
        Action act = new Action(() =>
        {
            while (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested!=true)
            {
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;

                byte[] data = new byte[2];
                if (lastRequestReplayed)
                {
                    _ping.SendAsync(_address, 30000, data, _address);
                    lastRequestReplayed = false;
                }
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                Thread.Sleep(_delay);
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
            }
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(act);
    }
}
```

and the problem with this code is it create One thread per sensor, that's mean if i had 500 target to ping i also have 500 threads! any suggestion? and so sorry for my bad English :D

Comment: One important note, this _will not_ start 500 threads.  This will **queue** 500 tasks, the runtime will decide how many threads are appropriate to execute based on the environment the code is running in, but a `Task` != thread. So if you actually need these 500 tasks to definitely run in parallel, then this is probably not a good solution for you.

Comment: thx for your comment, i understand that and i didn't test it really with 500 tasks yet, but for 70 target i get 70 threads and this is exactly my problem, some tasks stooped for long time and its may take 30 seconds for one task to work again

Comment: Do you have the option to use .Net 4.5?

Comment: yes, there is no problem to use 4.5

Comment: This sounds like a timer problem, not a tasking problem. Set a timer for each ping job, have it call back with its listed ID. Keep a List<Tuple> holding the ID, IP, and the timer timespan. When the timer callback gets called, us the ID to look in your List<Tuple>, launch your ping task against that IP, and reset the timer with the correct time span and ID for that ID. Done.

Comment: i'm not sure that using 500 Timer is a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can demonstrate the concept with working code sample.. up to you to transform into code which suits your scenario 100%

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Pick your long list of ip address
            List<IPAddress> ips = new List<IPAddress>
            {
                new IPAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1}),
                new IPAddress(new byte[] {198, 252, 206, 16}),
                new IPAddress(new byte[] {74, 125, 129, 99}),
                // Add more ips as you like
            };

            // Exactly what do you do with initiated tasks will depend on your specific scenario.
            List<Task> tps = new List<Task>();

            foreach(var ip in ips)
            {
                // Delay could vary by IP, but I am hardcoding 10s here.
                tps.Add(InitiatePings(ip, 10000));
            }

            // Needed so that console app doesn't exit..
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task InitiatePings(IPAddress ip, int delay)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Note, this API is different from SendAsync API you are using
                // You may also want to reuse Ping instance instead of creating new one each time.
                var result = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip);
                // Process your result here, however you want.
                Console.WriteLine(result.Address + "-" + result.Status + "-" + result.RoundtripTime);
                // Assumes that the delay is not absolute, but time between ping, result processing and next ping.
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) for each IP address that you want to ping? That is:

```
List<System.Threading.Timer> timers = new List<System.Threading.Timer>();
```

You add the individual timers with:

```
timers.Add(new Timer(PingTimerProc, "192.168.1.1", 400, 400));
timers.Add(new Timer(PingTimerProc, "10.10.200.50", 42000, 42000));
// add other timers
```

And your timer proc:

```
void PingTimerProc(object state)
{
    string ipAddress = (string)state;
    // do the ping here
}
```

The only potential drawback here is that with a sufficiently large number of IP addresses that you need to ping very frequently, you run the risk of not being able to process all the timer events quickly enough. That will eventually lead to thrashing because you'll have a bunch of pending threads.

If you do this with a single thread and you have that many pings at such short intervals, you'll just start to fall behind. It won't end up killing your process.

If I were to do it with a single thread, I'd create a priority queue of IP addresses and their associated ping times. And a long-running task set to service that queue. The basic structure would be something like this:

```
class PingJob
{
    string IPAddress;
    int Period;  // milliseconds between pings
    TimeSpan NextPingTime;
}

var queue = new PriorityQueue<PingJob>();

// create the ping jobs and add them to the queue
queue.Add(new PingJob { IPAddress = "192.168.1.1", Period = 400, NextPingTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400) });
queue.Add(new PingJob { IPAddress = "10.10.200.50", Period = 42000, NextPingTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(42000) });
// etc.

// start a thread that processes the pings
var pingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(PingTaskProc, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

And the task proc:

```
void PingTaskProc()
{
    var pingTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
        var p = queue.Dequeue(); // get ping job
        if (p.NextPingTime > pingTimer.Elapsed)
        {
            // wait for ping time to come up
            Thread.Sleep(p.NextPingTime - pingTimer.Elapsed);
        }
        // ping the IP address
        DoPing(p.IPAddress);
        // update its next ping time
        p.NextPingTime += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(p.Period);
        // And add it back to the queue
        queue.Add(p);
    }
}
```

That assumes that you have a generic priority queue data structure available. There are many available, including [mine](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/12/18/posting-the-heap-code/).

Things get a bit more interesting if you can add and remove IP addresses from the queue, or change their ping periods. But you didn't specify that.